# mysql left join need order by and group by on right table

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

for simple, I write an example like this

```
select
a.xx,
a.xx,
...  -- all table a's field

b.date,
b.money

c.date,
c.money,

d.date,
d.money,

e.date,
e.money

from 
a
left join b on a.id = b.a_id
left join c on a.id = c.a_id
left join d on a.id = d.a_id
left join e on a.id = e.a_id

where ... -- some condition
limit 10
```

In this sql, table `b` and `c` is one to one to table `a`
but table `d` and `e` is not that.

With no optimization. table `d` and `e` while seem like this

```
-- ... sql before
left join
(
    select * from
    (select * from d order by date desc) as temp
    group by a_id
) as d on a.id = d.a_id

left join
(
    select * from
    (select * from e order by id desc) as temp
    group by a_id
) as e on a.id = e.a_id
-- ... sql after
```

But in fact, it is very slow when running this.
table `d` was a new table, it didn't has larges of data yet(it will be large in future).
table `e` had million now. subquery of table `e` make my sql very slow. How to optimization it?

Comment: remove those `order by` in your subqueries, its no use.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ ”its no use“ means "it doesn't work" or "it is unnecessary"? if the latter one, l must told that it is necessary, because I only need the latest date in `d` and the newest record in `e`

Comment: if you only need the latest record you limit your subquery. `(select * from d order by date desc limit 1)`

Comment: maybe I didn't talk clear, I means,  I need latest date in every a_id(the some in table `e`),  like "a_id - value" : "1 - 1", "1 - 2","1 - 4","2 - 1","2 - 5" I need "1 - 4" and "2 - 5"

Comment: if you need the latest date every a_id, it think you are referring to something like this `(select max(date), a_id from d group by a_id)`

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ   yes, you said right, but to see my example, I need `date`, `money` two field, that's why I did `order by` and then `group by`

Comment: Your ''order by group by' trick is a hack that cannot be guaranteed to work. If it was me , I'd see  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and start over

Comment: Nesting like that only slows things down.  What was wrong with the original?

Comment: Do you have `INDEX(a_id), INDEX(b_id)`, etc?

Comment: Sounds like a "groupwise max" problem.